# How to get the associated popup menu?

Tags: dynamic, import

I have three`PopupMenu` and they work in such a way that second `PopupMenu` value depends on the value selected by the first `PopupMenu` and third `PopupMenu` value depends on the second `PopupMenu` value being selected.

If first `PopupMenu` has two option a and b. Then second `PopupMenu` should have c,d,e if a is selected and f when b is selected.

And if c is selected from second `PopupMenu` then third `PopupMenu` should have g,h and so on.
These options are imported from Excel files. I wanted this to be dynamic; if someone makes any change to this file, then it should work accordingly.

At the starting time, all three `PopupMenu` should show Popup1, Popup2, Popup3 as the name of `PopupMenu` and the selected value should be shown in its title name from White color and all `PopupMenu` background is black.

Comment: As a general strategy, you could run a scheduled task each n seconds and test the file date there.

Comment: Yes. And except If, is there any other way to associate all the three popupmenu

Comment: Would the following do what you want? `menu2[a]=PopupMenu[x,{c,d,e}];menu2[b]=PopupMenu[x,{f}];{PopupMenu[Dynamic[y],{a,b}],Dynamic[menu2[y]]}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part of your question can be done very simply by making dynamic popupmenues where the options are related to the choices of the other popupmenues:

```
 PopupMenu[Dynamic[varA], {a, b}]
 Dynamic[PopupMenu[Dynamic[varB], Switch[varA, a, {c, d, e}, b, {f}, _, {}]]] 
 Dynamic[PopupMenu[Dynamic[varC], Switch[varB, c, {g, h}, _, {"So on"}]]]
```

Hopefully someone else will be able to help with the best way to integrate this with Excel.

Comment: I just noticed that you got the Populist badge.  Nice going. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you. :)

Comment: @jVincent: How can I use ActionMenu with Switch if I have to assign some action also in second Popupmenu

Comment: @Jennifer Unless I am misunderstanding your question, you should be able to just switch out `PopupMenu` with `ActionMenu`. If you are having trouble, you could extend your question.

Comment: @jVincent: I have edited.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar type of problem, I have created the associated menus in a different way though.

```
 i := Position[{a, b, c, d}, Item1][[1, 1]]
    Menu1 := PopupMenu[Dynamic[Item1], {a, b, c, d}, a];
    Menu2 := PopupMenu[Dynamic[Item2], {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11,12}}[[i]],{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}[[i]][[1]]]
    Value1 := Item2*10;
```

Testing it

```
 Dynamic[i]

 Dynamic[Menu1]

 Dynamic[Item1]

 Dynamic[Menu2]

 Dynamic[Item2]

 Dynamic[Value1]
```